# can not boot into ubuntu 12.10 only xp

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 12.10 using windows installer.
When I rebooted the machine, it gave me the option of booting into xp or ubuntu.
The arrow keys would not work.
It was set on xp and I could not get it onto ubuntu.
So it booted onto xp.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

**Try plugging in a different keyboard:**

You should try plugging in a corded USB or PS/2 keyboard, usually bluetooth keyboards don't work on lower level prompts. If you're not using a bluetooth keyboard you should still try plugging in a different keyboard.